# Method that checks if two items collide

Tags: refactoring, collision-detection

I am using the following method to check if 2 items share the same index:

```
function doIndexesColide(itemA,itemB){
    return ((itemA.startIndex >= itemB.startIndex) && (itemA.startIndex <= itemB.endIndex))
        || ((itemA.endIndex >= itemB.startIndex) && (itemA.endIndex <= itemB.endIndex))
        || ((itemA.startIndex <= itemB.startIndex) && (itemA.endIndex >= itemB.endIndex))

}
```

Which works fine , but i feel it could be a simpler method and would like to refactor.

This is the spec for the method - given 2 items with start-end index values , return true/false if items collide (consider only the start/end index , this is not a graphic collision detection but only consider the indexes)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [codereview.se].